# Will Jquery ui css styles overwrite my css styles?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I downloaded the Jquery ui along with one of there pre-made css styles.  I put all of this in a master page where I have some of my styles.  Will the jquery styles, for example, the ones for anchor tags overwrite the styles I have for my anchor tags.  I basically just want the jquery styles to be just for the jquery ui components.  Is there a way to prevent style overwriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the .css file for jquery ui, you will find that it does not override any standard tags.  All classes are prefixed with `ui-`.  It is likely that this overriding behavior is caused by something else.

To debug css precedence issues, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) are very useful.  You may wish to use one of these tools to determine the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, nothing is actually being overwritten for now, I was just curious if it would.